Ubuntu OpSys Updates leave screen all black
OpSys updates accepted as usual yesterday (June 6, 2024), update and restart. On restart screen is all black. Had to hit escape after another shut down and restart to access recovery mode. That worked. But now, leaving laptop on over night resulted in all black screen again in morning. Shut down and restarted. Needed to access recovery mode again to avoid all black screen. What to do to fix? So far it looks like this issue is not going away.
Appears that timing out to screen lock or using session suspend leads to black screen with no way to "awake" out of black screen.
Acer, Aspire 515-43, BIOS Information Vendor: Insyde Corp. Version: V1.11 Release Date: 11/16/2020 Address: 0xE0000 Runtime Size: 128 kB ROM Size: 4608 kB ,Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series], GNOME desktop –
CA1Greco
Boot options. No black screen with 5.15.0-107 -generic selection
Stuck black screen with latest Linux 5.15.0-112-generic (recovery version needed to eliminate black screen)
No stuck black screen with previous Linux 5.15.0-107-generic (recovery version not needed).

Not enough info. We need computer make, model, firmware version, GPU and driver, and the desktop you're using to even take a guess.

Please edit the question and add the info requested. Comments are for people trying to assist you to ask for info.
